# Why does installed version differ than what apt-cache madison indicates?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, ffmpeg

I recently installed `ffmpeg` on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. When I run `ffmpeg -version` the output is:

```
ffmpeg version N-81995-gd790e48 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
```

I installed this version with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

I was also recently told that the following command can be used to see what version of a binary/lib `apt-get` will install:

```
apt-cache madison <name_of_binary>
```

But when I run `apt-cache madison ffmpeg` on my Ubuntu server, the output is:

```
ffmpeg | 7:3.1.4+git1~trusty | http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

**I'm wondering why I'm seeing a version difference between these two commands.** Why does `ffmpeg -version` say my version is `N-81995-gd790e48`, yet the other command states `7:3.1.4+git1~trusty` is the version that should be getting installed?

Comment: Use `apt-cache policy PACKAGENAME` to see all package installation candidates for a package, not `apt-cache madison`.  (It will also indicate which source provides that specific candidate).  Also note one may be a revision number in the binary (with a revision tag in hexadecimal), while one may be the actual version represented in the Ubuntu changelogs.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard (+1) - however that doesn't seem to work for all binaries/libs. For instance, I had used `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` to install the PNG library, but when I run `apt-cache policy libpng-dev` I get output that says: `libpng-dev: Installed: (none) \ Candidate: (none)`. Any thoughts there? Thanks again!

Comment: It will only list what's available from your sources - as well, some packages are "virtual packages" which don't actually exist and wouldn't show up in the output (nor in `madison`)

Comment: Hmmm, so if I am about to install `libpng-dev` on a new Ubuntu 14.04 box, how can I tell (ahead of time) what version will be installed if I were to run `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`?

Comment: You may have multiple `ffmpeg` binaries on your system. Do a search, or look in `~/bin` or elsewhere in your `PATH`.